# Show glyphicon-remove Bootstrap when the text is inserted

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My index.html:

```
<input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search..." >
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="search-bar-icon-clear"></span>
```

I would like to show the icon when the text is inserted.
example:

[image]
[image]
Show icon
[image]

Comment: At least show what you have tried doing. Anyway, this can be achieved with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a JQuery solution for your problem. please use the CSS and JQuery to build your element. I am using the same glyphicon for both side, please use the correct one.

```js
$('.custom-input > input').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $(this).siblings('span').show();
  }else{
    $(this).siblings('span').hide();
  };
})
```

```css
.custom-input {
  position: relative;
}

.custom-input > input {
  padding: 0px 17px;
}

.custom-input > span:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  height: 14px;
  top: calc(50% - 7px);
  display: none;
}

.custom-input > span:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  height: 14px;
  top: calc(50% - 7px);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group custom-input">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="search-bar-icon-clear"></span>
  <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="search-bar-icon-clear"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an exemple of how you can do it :

```js
function showClear(id){

var input =document.getElementById(id).value;
if (input !=""){

document.getElementById("search-bar-icon-clear").style.display="block";
}

if(input ==""){
document.getElementById("search-bar-icon-clear").style.display="none";
}
}
```

```css
.right-inner-addon {
  position: relative;
 
}

.right-inner-addon input {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.right-inner-addon span {
  position: absolute;
 left:25%;
  padding: 1%;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:none;
 
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="right-inner-addon ">
<input type="text" class="search-input" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search...."  onkeyup="showClear(this.id)" >
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="search-bar-icon-clear"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple javascript (jQuery) here, Like:

```
// 'keyup' is triggered whenever any key is pressed on input
$('.search-input').on('keyup', function() {
  if($(this).val() != '') {
    $('#search-bar-icon-clear').addClass('show');
  } else {
    $('#search-bar-icon-clear').removeClass('show');
  }
});
```

So basically in the above code, you are checking if the `.search-input` has some text, then add class `show` else remove the class. And the if class `show` is present with icon then display the icon like:

```
#search-bar-icon-clear.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```js
$('.search-input').on('keyup', function() {
  if($(this).val() != '') {
    $('#search-bar-icon-clear').addClass('show');
  } else {
    $('#search-bar-icon-clear').removeClass('show');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.search-holder {
  position: relative;
}

.search-input {
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px;
}

#search-bar-icon-clear {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 15px;
}

#search-bar-icon-clear.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-holder">
  <input type="text" class="search-input form-control" placeholder="Search..." >
  <span class="fa fa-remove" id="search-bar-icon-clear"></span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!